# HTML post to PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

Trying to insert data into my table but I keep getting an undefined index because there are "no value set when I submit my form". The `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` removes my error even when I run the .php alone but no data is inserted when I submit my form. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

My form.html

```
<form name="supportForm" class="form" action="database.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

<label>Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<br/>

<label>Client ID:</label>
<input type="text" name="clientID"/>
<br/>

<label>E-mail address:</label>
<input type="email" name="email"/>
<br/>

<label>Phone number:</label>
<input type="tel" name="tel"/>
<br/>

<br/>
Support Type:<br>
<input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Question/Inquiry">Question/Inquiry<br>
<input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Software">Software Issue<br>
<input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Hardware">Hardware Issue<br>
<input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Connectivity">Connectivity<br>
</br>

Operating System:
<select id="select">
    <option disabled selected value="">Choose a product</option>
    <option value="w7" name="OS">Windows 7</option>
    <option value="w8" name="OS">Windows 8/8.1</option>
    <option value="w10" name="OS">Windows 10</option>
</select>

<br> </br>

Problem Description:
<br><textarea id="ta" rows="10" cols="80" name="pDesc"></textarea></br>

<input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="agree">
<a href="#">I agree to the terms and conditions.</a>

<br> </br>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="validateSubmit()">
</form>
```

My PHP file

```
<?php
//Creates static credentials
define('DB_NAME', 'data');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

//Creates connection to the database
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

//Checks for connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

//If there are no connection, error
if (!$con) {
    die ('Could not connect' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select the 'data' database
$con->select_db(DB_NAME);

//Checks if database 'data' has been selected
if (mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME)) {
    echo "Database exists <br>";
} else {
    echo "Database does not exist";
}

//Successful connection message
echo "Connected successfully <br>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//Retrieving values from support form
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $clientID = $_POST['clientID'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $suppType = $_POST['suppType'];
    $OS = $_POST['OS'];
    $pDesc = $_POST['pDesc'];

//Inserting values into a table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO info (fullname, clientID, email, tel,
    suppType, OS, pDesc)
    VALUES ($name, $clientID, $email, $tel, 
    $suppType, $OS, $pDesc)";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    echo "No data";
} else {
    echo "Data recorded successfully";
}
}

//Closes connection
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: update the code of `validateSubmit()`

Comment: You'll not get the proper results because you should be adding single quotes around your `$_POST` values. But it's unsafe as well, you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or prepared statements.

Comment: Do you get your values in the `$_POST` in your php file? Do you get "No Data" error?

Comment: I think you don't need to set `onClick` and `onsubmit` attributes, because they're only javascript.

Comment: How would I update the validateSubmit() code or what should I be updating? And yes I do get the "No Data" message.

Comment: This is not all your code

Answer (score 3):

You must write `name="OS"` in `<select>` not in `<option>`

```
<select id="select" name="OS">
    <option disabled selected value="">Choose a product</option>
    <option value="w7">Windows 7</option>
    <option value="w8">Windows 8/8.1</option>
    <option value="w10">Windows 10</option>
</select>
```

And Sql must be like this you need apostrophes (`''`) around variables

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `info` (fullname, clientID, email, tel, suppType, OS, pDesc)
VALUES ('$name', '$clientID', '$email', '$tel', '$suppType', '$OS', '$pDesc')";
```

Comment: It's the problem, But not main problem!

Answer (score 1):

You not showing us the validateForm() function, therefore we won't really know whats happening there, nonetheless I have edited your form and did a validation using php,

what you need to do first is to check if all values are set before jumping to insert into db, and make sure email is a proper email, also the select option the name attribute needs to be on the select tag not on the option tag, the option must only have values.

> Then Validate,Filter and sanitize user input before storing to the
>   database. Treat every userinput on your form as if its from a very dangerous hacker.

There's something called prepared statements, in mysqli and PDO you should try to learn that and use it :) you will enjoy it, I will leave it to you to research as to why you need to use prepared statements.

This is how your code should look

```
<form name="supportForm" class="form" action="database.php" method="POST">
   <label>Name:</label>
   <input type="text" name="name"/>
   <br/>
   <label>Client ID:</label>
   <input type="text" name="clientID"/>
   <br/>
   <label>E-mail address:</label>
   <input type="email" name="email"/>
   <br/>
   <label>Phone number:</label>
   <input type="tel" name="tel"/>
   <br/>
   <br/>
   Support Type:<br>
   <input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Question/Inquiry">Question/Inquiry<br>
   <input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Software">Software Issue<br>
   <input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Hardware">Hardware Issue<br>
   <input type="radio" name="suppType" value="Connectivity">Connectivity<br>
   </br>
   Operating System:
   <select id="select" name="OS">
      <option value="0">Choose a product</option>
      <option value="w7">Windows 7</option>
      <option value="w8">Windows 8/8.1</option>
      <option value="w10">Windows 10</option>
   </select>
   <br> </br>
   Problem Description:
   <br>
   <textarea id="ta" rows="10" cols="80" name="pDesc"></textarea>
   </br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="terms" value="agree">
   <a href="#">I agree to the terms and conditions.</a>
   <br> </br>
   <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
   <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then **database.php**

```
<?php
//Creates static credentials
define('DB_NAME', 'data');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$errors = ""; //checking for errors

//Creates connection to the database
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

//Checks for connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}

//If there are no connection, error
if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect' . mysqli_error());
}

//Select the 'data' database
$con->select_db(DB_NAME);

//Checks if database 'data' has been selected
if (mysqli_select_db($con, DB_NAME)) {
        echo "Database exists <br>";
} else {
        echo "Database does not exist";
}

//Successful connection message
echo "Connected successfully <br>";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        //check values are set

        if (empty($_POST['name'])) {

                echo "enter name";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $name = userIput($_POST['name']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['clientID'])) {

                echo "enter id";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $clientID = userIput($_POST['clientID']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['email'])) {

                echo "enter email";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $email = userIput($_POST['email']);

                if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) { //validate email,

                        echo "enter valid email";
                        $errors++;
                }
        }

        if (empty($_POST['tel'])) {

                echo "enter tel";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $tel = userIput($_POST['tel']);
        }

        if (!isset($_POST['suppType'])) {

                echo "select one option";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $suppType = userIput($_POST['suppType']);
        }

        if (isset($_REQUEST['OS']) && $_REQUEST['OS'] === "0") {

                echo "please select product";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $OS = userIput($_POST['OS']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['pDesc'])) {

                echo "enter Description";
                $errors++;
        } else {

                $pDesc = userIput($_POST['pDesc']);
        }


        if ($errors <= 0) { // No errors

                //prepare and insert query

                $sql = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO info (fullname, clientID, email, tel,suppType, OS, pDesc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                $sql->bind_param("sssssss", $name, $clientID, $email, $tel, $suppType, $OS, $pDesc);
                if ($sql->execute()) {

                        echo "records inserted successfully";
                } else {

                        echo "Could not insert " . mysqli_error();
                }



                $sql->close();
                $con->close();




        }

}

function userIput($data)
{

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;


}
?>
```

Hope this will help a little, and you will learn a thing or two, and I'm always available for suggessions, just incase I missed something. Thanks